# Android: One vs many instances of HttpClient per application

Tags: android, concurrency, singleton

Until recently, our app shared a single Apache HttpClient instance using the ThreadSafeClientConnManager across the whole application. The http client instance was held by a singleton class.

Since I dislike the singleton pattern for its numerous problems, I refactored our API accessor to be a per-thread object, but now for every thread (which mostly means per Activity/Service in our case) a new HttpClient instance is created.

It's not that I have problems with this new approach, but I've read that the Apache folks suggest to only have one instance per app for performance reasons.

Visually, what we did before was this:

```
HttpClient (thread safe)
          |
          |
         /\
        /  \
Activity1...ActivityN
```

Now, we do this:

```
Activity1 ... ActivityN
    |             |
    |             |
HttpClient1   HttpClientN
```

How do you guys do this in your applications? If you share one single HttpClient across your app and potentially many concurrent threads, how do you handle access to it?

Comment: Could you zero-in on which approach is better the first one (Singleton) or second one?

Comment: I use the first approach now. A factory takes care of only instantiating one instance, which then uses ThreadSafeConnManager to cope with concurrent requests. I believe that's how AndroidHttpClient (FroYo and newer API levels) is set up, too. Works well with DI frameworks like Guice too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a nutshell:

Create an instance of `org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager` and use it when constructing a DefaultHttpClient.

Link to sample source:
[HttpClient multithreaded access](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java)

Edit: Sorry, didn't see your edit before posting.  There's nothing inherently wrong with "Singleton" in this case.

Comment: I've read (in the tutorial I believe) that it's perfectly fine to maintain a static HttpClient instance. I guess that's what I'll be doing then. That way I can get rid of the singleton and at the same time share one client instance across the app.

Comment: @Matthias: If you are doing a singleton with `HttpClient`, when are you calling `httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();`?